# React secured route

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router-v4

`react-router-dom` gives [this suggested implementation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) for authenticating routes.
However, It's not clear how to securely decide if the user is logged in or not (how to implement the `fakeAuth` function).
It seems that I have to make some kind of an `IsLoggedIn` network call which can be easily tampered once reached to the client.
My question is: how can I implement the `fakeAuth` in a more secured way?

Comment: Yes. you'd nee to have auth data to check login status. if someone fakes this it's primarily the job of your backend to validate that user is actually logged in on every other server call. there aremany reasons having authetication checks on the client could fail so your backend have to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: It really depends on the way you auth users. In one of the apps I've worked on, the backend returned a JWT token on successful initial authentication and it was stored in the localStorage. So the 'fakeAuth' in that case would be checking if the token is present in the storage or in state. Similar thing can be done with cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after banging my head on this for a while I came to realize that I'll have no way to avoid an `if(isLoggedIn()){...}` check on the client, regardless of the check itself (cookie, token or a network call).
What I'll do is have 2 separate html files, one for non-authenticated users (registration, login, forgot password etc.) and one for logged in users that will require the request to pass through the server, thus giving me the option to redirect the user when needed.